# My app deployed successfully in Heroku but in times of opening the app show error

Tags: node.js, heroku

My app successfully deployed to Heroku..

> ****: Deployed 6bc02eb8 Today at 4:19 PM · v23 ·
> Compare diff  **** ****: Build
> succeeded Today at 4:18 PM · View build log

But It shows error when try to open my app...

> 2022-06-29T10:19:45.228279+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
> 2022-06-29T10:19:45.228377+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the
> blog-application@1.0.0 start script. 2022-06-29T10:19:45.228470+00:00
> app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is
> likely additional logging output above.
> 2022-06-29T10:19:45.236802+00:00 app[web.1]:
> 2022-06-29T10:19:45.237020+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log
> of this run can be found in: 2022-06-29T10:19:45.237112+00:00
> app[web.1]: npm ERR!
> /app/.npm/_logs/2022-06-29T10_19_45_229Z-debug.log
> 2022-06-29T10:19:45.431649+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with
> status 1 2022-06-29T10:19:45.541882+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed
> from starting to crashed 2022-06-29T10:19:48.705353+00:00
> heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET
> path="/" host=syt-share-your-thoughts.herokuapp.com
> request_id=0bb2aaff-6bce-41fb-891e-d3b361a122f8 fwd="59.153.103.22"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
> 2022-06-29T10:19:51.151462+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
> host=syt-share-your-thoughts.herokuapp.com
> request_id=c0d24108-01a7-44b7-96dd-e8cc62bcaa7c fwd="59.153.103.22"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "blog-application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "author": "Md Shareful Islam",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "chalk": "^4.1.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.11",
    "config": "^3.3.7",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongodb-session": "^3.1.1",
    "debug": "^4.3.4",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.8",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.8",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "reading-time": "^1.5.0",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.15.5"
  }
}
```

And this is my main file:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const config = require('config')
const chalk = require('chalk')

// import middleware
const setMiddleware = require('./middleware/middleware')

//Import Routes
const setRoutes = require('./routes/routes')


const MONGODB_URI = `mongodb+srv://${config.get('db-admin')}:${config.get('db-password')}@blogapp.ool50gr.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

const app = express();

// Setup View Engine
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', 'views')

// Using Middleware from Middleware Directory
setMiddleware(app)

// Using Routes from Route Directory
setRoutes(app)

// ** middleware to handle 404 and 500.
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    let error = new Error('404 Page Not Found');
    error.status = 404;
    next(error);
})

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    if(error.status === 404) {
        return res.render('pages/error/404', {flashMessage: {}})
    }
    res.render('pages/error/500', {flashMessage: {}})
})

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI, 
{useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(() => {
    console.log(chalk.green.bold('Database connected!'))
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(chalk.green.italic(`App is running on PORT ${PORT}`));
    });
})
.catch(e => {
    return console.log(e)
})
```

Here are logs datails from Heroku...

```
2022-06-29T16:18:56.404997+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-06-29T16:18:56.405076+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-06-29T16_18_56_398Z-debug.log
2022-06-29T16:18:56.554135+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-06-29T16:18:56.637092+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-06-29T16:18:56.640222+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-06-29T16:19:00.220649+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-06-29T16:19:03.473783+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-06-29T16:19:03.473792+00:00 app[web.1]: > blog-application@1.0.0 start /app
2022-06-29T16:19:03.473792+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2022-06-29T16:19:03.473792+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-06-29T16:19:35.090006+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:417
2022-06-29T16:19:35.090017+00:00 app[web.1]:                     throw error;
2022-06-29T16:19:35.090018+00:00 app[web.1]:                     ^
2022-06-29T16:19:35.090019+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-06-29T16:19:35.090020+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Error connecting to db: connection <monitor> to 13.250.175.230:27017 closed
2022-06-29T16:19:35.090021+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/connect-mongodb-session/index.js:88:17
2022-06-29T16:19:35.090021+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:413:17
2022-06-29T16:19:35.090022+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:129:28
2022-06-29T16:19:35.090022+00:00 app[web.1]:     at connectCallback (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:29:9)
2022-06-29T16:19:35.090023+00:00 app[web.1]:     at /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js:78:20
2022-06-29T16:19:35.090023+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.callback (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:208:50)
2022-06-29T16:19:35.090024+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Timeout._onTimeout (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:319:33)
2022-06-29T16:19:35.090024+00:00 app[web.1]:     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:554:17)
2022-06-29T16:19:35.090024+00:00 app[web.1]:     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:497:7)
2022-06-29T16:19:35.109275+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2022-06-29T16:19:35.109568+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2022-06-29T16:19:35.113501+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! blog-application@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2022-06-29T16:19:35.113599+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2022-06-29T16:19:35.113705+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2022-06-29T16:19:35.113792+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the blog-application@1.0.0 start script.
2022-06-29T16:19:35.113876+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2022-06-29T16:19:35.120692+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2022-06-29T16:19:35.120808+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2022-06-29T16:19:35.120859+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2022-06-29T16_19_35_114Z-debug.log
2022-06-29T16:19:35.785417+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-06-29T16:19:35.273101+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-06-29T16:19:38.894464+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=syt-share-your-thoughts.herokuapp.com request_id=2b13bcd5-e764-4e60-a254-394a8b0f7531 fwd="59.153.103.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-06-29T16:19:41.185482+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=syt-share-your-thoughts.herokuapp.com request_id=6109b89a-818d-4827-804b-98c1a875a3ab fwd="59.153.103.22" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't provide enought information for us to be able to help you, nobody can or will debug it for you in that regard.

Here, sharing your `package.json` and the entry file of your application would be useful!

Anyway it seems that `npm run start` is crashing, you could start by making sure that whatever command is run by `npm run start` is accessible in heroku (You might use a global dependencies that you have installed on your local machine which heroku doesn't).

I'll be glad to help you more if you provide required code snippets for us to understand what's happening!

Comment: I have added my package.json and app.js file that may help you to find out where is my error.

Comment: Can you try to change `"main": "index.js"` to `"main": "app.js"` in the package.json?  
please post the heroku output if it still throws an error? (This might fix your error but I'm not sure tbh)

Comment: I have modified my package.json file according to your instruction

Comment: {
  "name": "blog-application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js",
    "dev": "nodemon app.js"
  },

Comment: still It is showing error...
Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
heroku logs --tail

Comment: I have added logs details with the question

Comment: Ok now it seems that the database connexion is the issue. Make sure this works in your dev environment and if so make sure that your MongoDB instance accepts connexion from the heroku remote server. 

However you added a `.catch()` to handle a connection error by logging it so I dont really know why it crashes on `mongoose.connect()`.

Comment: It works in my dev environment but in case of heroku does not work. doest it for **${config.get('db-admin')}:${config.get('db-password')}** in my app,js file?

Comment: can you `console.log()` your connection uri and check in the heroku logs if its get properly retrieved (don't post it here obv!)

Comment: mongodb+srv://****:****@blogapp.ool50gr.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
Database connected!
App is running on PORT 8080

Comment: 2022-06-30T08:39:23.508698+00:00 app[web.1]: mongodb+srv://***:***@blogapp.ool50gr.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
2022-06-30T08:39:12.018777+00:00 app[api]: Release v8 created by user ***
2022-06-30T08:39:12.018777+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 7798e3d0 by user ***
2022-06-30T08:39:12.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded

this is the result in heroku logs.. heroku can trace my uri.. I think another problem happened here

Comment: It is not working right now??  Your logs seems completely fine

Comment: yes..still it is not working... and I think it database related problem

Comment: You might only have authorized database connexions from your IP? So when hosted on heroku server, their IP isn't authorized to connect to mongodb instance. Have you donne something like that ?

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad we managed to fix it